# how to attach tags to morphMany relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want when upload a image and created model it, add related tags that user selected.
I'll do it now but i think this method not best way.
[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: paste codes is better than paste image

Comment: not exists error, I want use a better way for add tag to image like $image->tags()->attach($tag_id)

Comment: How do you define "a  better way"? Is there anything not working with the current code?

Answer (score 1):

You have moreMany relationship between Image and Tag,

So you can use [create method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) like this:

```php
$tag_array = array();
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    if(!is_numeric($tag)) {
        $tag_array []= ['name' => $tag, 'user_id' => auth()->id];
    }
}
// Use createMany with relationship
$image->tags()->createMany($tag_array);
```

This method will create many tags and build the relationship between them.
Or you can use `saveMany()`:

```php
$image->tags()->createMany(array(
    new Tag(['name' => 'xxx', 'user_id' => 1]),
    new Tag(['name' => 'xxx', 'user_id' => 2]),
    ...
));
```

If you have some tags already exists. you can use `sync()` like this:
This just for **polymorphic many-to-many**:

```php
$image->tags()->sync($tag_ids); // attach or detach tag_ids
$image->tags()->sync($tag_ids, false); // Not detach previous relations, attaches new ones skipping existing tag_ids
```

Comment: But some tags already exist and I create tag that already not exist but I want add all this tag to $image

Comment: this method just create tag, my tags array contains id of already exists tag and name of new tag that not exists like this [1, 3, 5, "airport", "airplane"]; how to relationship between exists and new tags?

Comment: @Ramineghbalian have the exists tag already build the relationship with image

Comment: but this methods give error because sync, attach and detach method not supported morphMany() relation

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany::sync()

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany::sync()

Comment: tags of image save in taggables table and taggables table have tag_id, taggable_id, taggable_type field

Comment: sorry, I though it is many-to-many, so it is one-to-many morph. It has no `sync()`

Comment: I have found problem, I used morphMany insted of morphToMany

Comment: @Ramineghbalian if your relationship is many-to-many, u need to use `morphToMany`